Bitbucket pipeline YAML
I'm proficient in frontend development but new with CI/CD.
Goal: Test and build a Next.js SSR project with a Bitbucket pipeline, deploy to Azure.
Question: My pipeline is working, but could you give me feedback if it's any good?

With the nodecustom cache, yarn install only took 3 seconds. But with the Playwright image (instead of node:20), it's
taking 34 seconds every time. How can I find out which caching path to use?
Should I use the Playwright image to build my project, or only in the testing step?
Would you use this pipeline on production?
Any other improvements for performance or better testing?

Context: I have a 'main' branch and 'production' branch. Only on production should we be able to deploy to Azure.
# bitbucket-pipelines.yml
definitions:
  caches:
    nextcache: .next/cache
    nodecustom:
      key:
        files:
          - yarn.lock
      path: ./node_modules

image: mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.44.1-jammy # node 20

pipelines:
  default:
    - parallel:
        - step:
            name: Test
            caches:
              - nodecustom
              - nextcache
            script:
              - yarn install
              - yarn test:ci
        - step:
            name: Lint
            caches:
              - nodecustom
              - nextcache
            script:
              - yarn install
              - yarn lint
        - step:
            name: Build and e2e test
            caches:
              - nodecustom
              - nextcache
            script:
              - yarn install
              - yarn build
              - yarn playwright test --project=chromium
            artifacts:
              - playwright-report/**

  branches:
    production:
      - parallel:
          fail-fast: true
          steps:
            - step:
                name: Test
                caches:
                  - nodecustom
                  - nextcache
                script:
                  - yarn install
                  - yarn test:ci
            - step:
                name: Lint
                caches:
                  - nodecustom
                  - nextcache
                script:
                  - yarn install
                  - yarn lint
            - step:
                name: Build and compress
                caches:
                  - nodecustom
                  - nextcache
                script:
                  - yarn install
                  - yarn build
                  - apt update && apt install zip
                  - zip -r app-$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER.zip . -x *.git* bitbucket-pipelines.yml
                artifacts:
                  - "*.zip"
            - step:
                name: Security Scan
                script:
                  # Run a security scan for sensitive data.
                  # See more security tools at https://bitbucket.org/product/features/pipelines/integrations?&category=security
                  - pipe: atlassian/git-secrets-scan:0.5.1
      - step:
          name: Deploy to Azure
          trigger: manual
          deployment: Production
          script:
            - pipe: atlassian/azure-web-apps-deploy:1.0.1
              variables:
                AZURE_APP_ID: $AZURE_APP_ID
                AZURE_PASSWORD: $AZURE_PASSWORD
                AZURE_TENANT_ID: $AZURE_TENANT_ID
                AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP: $AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP
                AZURE_APP_NAME: $AZURE_APP_NAME
                ZIP_FILE: app-$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER.zip

```

